# Access level seems to have gone from admin to editor

Tags: users, user-roles

I have a client with a wp site (4.2.2) hosted by GoDaddy.

Yesterday, when she logged in a number of links on the dashboard menu were missing = including plugins, settings. Others, like the godaddy link wouldn't give her access. She has previously been admin - and the only user.

When I looked in the user db (via phpmyadmin) I noticed that her level appeared to be 'editor'

So I then attempted to create myself as an admin via mysql (via [wp-beginners](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/)) which has worked before on other sites. However, it wouldn't work here. I thought if I was an admin, and could get in, I could raise her access. No joy.

We called GoDaddy who suggested it was a 'network error' which seems likely to be wrong.

Any ideas how I can raise her back to admin?

Comment: lol "network error". Guess you get what you pay for. When you say creating yourself as an admin "didn't work", what happened? Could you not log in? Or did you get a "cheatin' huh?" message? Or "You do not have permission..."?

Comment: Ii got a 'you do not have permission' error - and agree completely about 'you get what you pay for'

Comment: Ok, do you know what the table prefix is? Usually it's `wp_` unless you've configured it something else with `$table_prefix` in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: config file has this wp_xxxxxxx_ as the prefix. I inserted myself via phpmyadmin using the editor rather than write my own queries though.

Comment: Ok you need to check two things - firstly, that there is a serialized array in the options table with the option name `wp_xxxxxxx_user_roles`. Then you need to check in the user meta table that there is an entry with your user ID, and meta key `wp_xxxxxxx_capabilities` and value `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

Comment: thanks for your help - appreciate it - appears to have sorted itself.... weird.